# Write several statements into an anonymous function in R

Tags: r, anonymous-function, reporters

I want to include a plot into some MS Word document using the `reporteRs` library.

Here is how I include my plot :

```
doc = addPlot(doc, 
  fun = function() plot(
    km.as.one,
    mark.time=TRUE,
    conf.int=FALSE,
    cex=1,
    col="blue",
    xlab = "Délai en années", ylab = "Pourcentage",
    lty=1:3,
  ),
  vector.graphic = TRUE, width = 5, height = 4,
  par.properties = parProperties(text.align = "center")
)
```

My problem is that I would like to add some error bars, customize the axis and maybe add the title, by adding something like following :

```
axis(1, at = seq(0, 36, by = 6))
with (data=summary.km.as.one, expr=errbar(time, surv, upper, lower, add=TRUE, pch=0.5, cap=0.02))
```

I have to write this outside of the `plot` statement, but I couldn't find how to write it in the anonymous function.

**Is it even possible to write several statements in an anonymous function ?**

**If yes, what is the right way, and if not, is there any workaround ?**

Comment: You just need to use `{}` to contain all your statements. So `fun=function() { plot(...); axis(...); with(...)}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add braces `{ }` and you can add multiple lines:

```
doc = addPlot(doc, 
  fun = function() { 
    # line 1
    # line 2
    # etc...
  },
  vector.graphic = TRUE, width = 5, height = 4,
  par.properties = parProperties(text.align = "center")
)
```

Comment: I wonder how could I not see this in all those tutorials... Thanks sir !

Comment: @DanChaltiel No problem. As a style suggestion it's a good idea to always include braces for `if`, `for`, and functions even if they're only going to be one line. That way it's visually clear what lines are in those blocks and also lets you easily add lines in the future.