# R using set.seed() within a purrr::map iteration structure

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

When generating new data in R, I can use set.seed() to ensure that I get the same data sets every time the code is run:

```
set.seed(12345)
a <- rnorm(500, mean = 50, sd = 10)
set.seed(12345)
b <- rnorm(500, mean = 50, sd = 10)
identical(a, b)
# TRUE
```

If I comment out the  set.seed() lines, `identical(a,b)` returns `FALSE`.

Now I want to use a `purrr::map()` structure to generate multiple data sets with slightly different parameters:

```
library(tidyverse)

means <- c(40, 50, 60)
sds <- c(9, 10, 11)

set.seed(12345)
data <- map2(
  means,
  sds,
  ~
    rnorm(500, mean = .x, sd = .y)
    )
```

The `map2()` call generates a list of three data frames. With this relatively simple operation, I get identical data frames every time I run the code. But I'm finding that with more complex, longer functional pipelines involving certain packages (e.g., `bestNormalize`), I'm not getting identical output when the `set.seed()` command is *outside* the iterative looping structure of `map()`.

I'm at a loss for how to bring `set.seed()` *within* the `map()` iteration structure so that it is called anew at the beginning of each iteration. To be clear, the larger goal is to be able to iterate over functions that use random number generation, and to get identical results every time. Perhaps there's a better way to accomplish this in the `tidyverse` that doesn't depend on `set.seed()`. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a followup, here is the most concise way to solve my original problem:

```
library(tidyverse)

means <- c(40, 50, 60)
sds <- c(9, 10, 11)

data <- map2(
  means,
  sds,
  ~ {
    set.seed(12345)
    rnorm(500, mean = .x, sd = .y)
  }
)
```

This code returns identical results each time it is run.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your question as how to position the seed inside the map call:

```
means <- c(40, 50, 60)
sds <- c(9, 10, 11)

myfun <- function(means, sds){
    set.seed(12345) # set it before each call
    ret <- rnorm(500, mean = means, sd = sds)
    return(ret)
}

data <- purrr::map2(means,
                    sds,
                    ~ myfun(.x, .y))
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks very much. Do you think it's possible to write `myfun()` as an anonymous function within the `map2()` call?

Comment: @DSH this should be possible... I do not use anoymous functions but according to this link it is quite simple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205058/write-several-statements-into-an-anonymous-function-in-r